# Get all users attached to a taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, users

I have created a taxonomy called "user_category"

I am able to obtain the id of the term from the current logged in user -

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$terms = get_the_terms($current_user->ID, 'user_category' );
```

With the id for this term, I then want to find all other users that have this same term id.

I have the following, however this does not work, it will return a post -

```
$args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'user_category',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => 2 // This being the id 
            )
        )
    );
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: not sure what you expect `get_posts` to return if not a post. On a more basic level it is not very clear what is it that you try to do at all

Comment: Obviously get_posts is not what I require. What I need is a list of users that are assigned to the same tax as the current logged in user.

Comment: users are not content, you should not use taxonomies with them

Comment: you can group them with a meta value or role if that is what you want to do

Comment: What is the best way for me to group them then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Wordpress function [get_objects_in_term](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_objects_in_term/)

```
$users = get_objects_in_term(2, 'user_category'); // 2 being term id
```

This return array of users that have this same term id.